# How to link to a html page in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

How do i link/redirect to a html page that has it own cdn in vue.js
These html page are some old project that i made in the past that i want to link to.
I have only install the webpack-simple and vue-router.

```
<div id="navMenu">

  <ul>

       <li class="project">   
         <a :href="publicPath + 'project/projectOne/drone.html'">Drone</a> 
       </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

The script

```
<script>

  export default {

    data () {
      return {

        publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL
      }
    },
    methods:{

    }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: I'd just use a normal `<a href="...">` to link to static assets outside of Vue.

Comment: @DanielBeck when i do it, i get a blank page with Cannot GET /assets/project/projectOne/drone.html

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry; you also need to make sure webpack knows about the static files (easiest way, assuming you're using vue-cli, is to use the `public` folder: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder)

Comment: @DanielBeck can you help me out a little bit more i have put the code on the display.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are static files, separate from your Vue project, that you don't need to run through webpack, and that you're using vue-cli for scaffolding:

Put the static files inside the `public` directory (at the root level of your project).  Anything you put in there will be copied directly into the `dist` folder at build -- so `public/foo.html` would wind up at the root level inside `dist`; `/public/project/projectOne/drone.html` would wind up in `/dist/project/projectOne/drone.html`, etc.

Link to those files from within your Vue project as you would any normal external site or file (using the project BASE_URL if necessary):

```
<!-- assuming the source file is in /public/project/projectOne/drone.html -->
<a :href="publicPath + 'project/projectOne/drone.html'">Drone</a>         

export default {
    data () {
      return {
        publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL
      }
    }
    // ...
```

Comment: I have created a folder name public and put it in the root level with your code but i now get Cannot GET /undefinedproject/projectOne/drone.html with a  undefined instead.

Comment: That looks like the BASE_URL is undefined.  Are you using vue-cli?   I just noticed you mention "simple-webpack", if you mean [this](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple) is your whole webpack setup then you're going to be missing a lot of important stuff, that's really just for quick tests and mockups.

Comment: Yes i have only install the webpack-simple and vue-router. What more do i need to install then?

Comment: [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org) is the de facto standard (I apologize for not realizing you weren't using it already).  Or you could leave your project as is and host / link to these html files externally.